# PHP - locale information gone after PDO connection (DB2)

Tags: php, pdo, db2, locale

Is there any reason why PHP loses all locale information after connecting to DB2 with PDO?

I always have to set the locale information again after a connnection.

```
<?PHP
//set locale information
setlocale( LC_MONETARY,'en_US' );

//print location information
print_r(localeconv());

//    Array
//    (
//      [decimal_point] => .
//      [thousands_sep] => 
//      [int_curr_symbol] => USD 
//      [currency_symbol] => $
//      [mon_decimal_point] => .
//      [mon_thousands_sep] => ,
//      ...
//    )

//************************************************
//create conenction to server
$connection= new PDO("odbc:server", 'username', 'password');
//************************************************

//see locale information after creating a connection
print_r(localeconv());

//    Array
//    (
//      [decimal_point] => .
//      [thousands_sep] => 
//      [int_curr_symbol] => 
//      [currency_symbol] => 
//      [mon_decimal_point] => 
//      [mon_thousands_sep] => 
//      ...
//
//    )
?>
```

Comment: Are you on a (multi-threaded) webserver where other PHP-scripts (that may also utilize `setlocale()`) are being run simultaneously? If so, be sure to read [this note in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php#refsect1-function.setlocale-notes).

Comment: we use Linux with Apache MPM (default setup)

Comment: I am unable to duplicate your problem. I'm testing on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS running Apache 2.2.22 and PHP 5.3.10. When I execute **apache2 -l** I see _prefork.c_. Here's my PDO connection command: **$this->db_connection = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};SYSTEM=$this->he_database_server;PROTOCOL=TCPIP", $temp_username, $temp_password);**

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, then there is general problem that setlocale() doesn't work. In my case it switched to base locale at random point in script, at the time of script was run. I had win 7 professional 64bit. No other script were running at that time.